# Export html with jquery including pagination

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am facing the problem that with the code snippet I got from somewhere on the Internet I can perfectly create a xls. file from my html table (created with mysql/php) but it doesn't show all results. It only grabs the rows that it sees on the front end. But I am using pagination and there are other results in the background. How can I adjust the code so it also grabs the information from the other pages.

```
var tableToExcel = (function () {
    var uri =
        'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
        template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
     xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso
     9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
        base64 = function (s) {
            return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
        }, format = function (s, c) {
            return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                return c[p];
            })
        }
    return function (table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = {
            worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
            table: table.innerHTML
        }
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) plugin or jQuery. It handles pagination, export to excel, plus heaps of other cool stuff you can do to data tables.

It'll save you having a complicated JS function like the one you've posted above.

Comment: Yes thank you. I done that already. But when I insert the 
function I always get an error message: DataTables warning (table id = 'a1'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

To retrieve the DataTables object for this table, pass no arguments or see the docs for bRetrieve and bDestro

Comment: I would create a new question about that, rather than trying to get it fixed here. Make sure to include your table HTML, and the exact javascript you're running, along with the error.  I think there'll be a real benefit in getting DataTables working for you instead of trying to get bits and pieces of scripts working from across the web.

Comment: Although, Google seems to say that error is likely because you're running the javascript before the table has been loaded on the page. Try having the script below the table and see if that makes a difference :-)

Comment: @ChrisMcKinnel It requires flash to be installed on user machine. Is there any solution without using swf file?